# setContentView(int) not working

Tags: java, android

i am trying to work through a tutorial and have run across a bit of a snag. the tutorial
 implements a class SingleFragmentActivity to host a fragment (with the xml file to go along with it.

My issue is in this SingleFragmentActivity.java class, there is a call to setContentView(int) that is throwing an error, its says it cannot find the method. Isn't setContentView(int) part of the Fragment Class?

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends Fragment {
   protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = createFragment();
        manager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
            .commit();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.app.Fragment` has its view initialized in `onCreateView`. Basically you need to use inflater to inflate your view and return it as root view in `onCreateView`.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle))

And the example in the link

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        // We have different layouts, and in one of them this
        // fragment's containing frame doesn't exist.  The fragment
        // may still be created from its saved state, but there is
        // no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
        // won't be displayed.  Note this is not needed -- we could
        // just run the code below, where we would create and return
        // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
        return null;
    }

    ScrollView scroller = new ScrollView(getActivity());
    TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
    int padding = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            4, getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    text.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    scroller.addView(text);
    text.setText(Shakespeare.DIALOGUE[getShownIndex()]);
    return scroller;
}
```

Besides, if you want to use `setContentView`, use `FragmentActivity` in the support library.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong way. setContentView(int) will work for `Activity` but your class is extending Fragment so you need to inflate the xml and return the view in the `onCreateView`

This is for example :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout. activity_fragment, container, false);
        // Do some Initialization
        return view;
    }
```

And for a little note, don't name your fragment class with Activity. It will make you confused :)

Answer (score 1):

`setContentView` is not a member of `Fragment`. To inflate a view for a fragment, you need to return the view to `onCreateView` after inflating it:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment make use of onCreateView() and inflate instead of onCreate() and onContentView() which is specific for Activities